# jQuery hide all elements with the same id

Tags: jquery

by topic I have some divs with id = "loader".

In my jQuery code I have

```
  $("#loader").hide(),
```

but it works only with the first div.

How could I hide all the divs?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Html not allow multiple #ID on element on same page. You can use .class either. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha, multiple IDs are very well allowed on an HTML page, but no two elements on the same page can have the same ID.

Comment: @ahren, `<div id="elem1"><div> <div id="elem2"></div>` - this is right.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Can you please show me in html5 validator

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed You can put elem1, elem2 but not elem on multiple elements. The code not broken sometime (CSS will work) but you can't validate it.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed - obviously we're talking about multiple *identical* IDs.

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha, is the code snippet I put in my comment to ahren invalid in html5 ?

Comment: nope, but <div id="elem"></div> used multiple time will invalid.

Comment: well if it is an ID it should be unique

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Having more than one element with the same ID is not valid HTML. You can only have one element with the ID (`#loader`) in the whole page. That's why jQuery is hiding only the first element. Use the class instead of the id:

```
$('.loader').hide();
```

Comment: 'only one ID in whole page' - !! no two elements with the same id instead, right ?

Answer (score 26):

The ids of html elements should be **unique** so you better use class with all element and use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to hide them all.

```
$('.className').hide();
```

If it is not possible for you to assign common class to them for instance you `can not` change the source code you can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
 $("[id=loader]").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use also :

```
$(".elementsToHideClass").addClass('hide');
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -3):

A way to hide all items of the same ID was as follows

```js
$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
  $('div#hidden').hide();
});
```

```html
<div id="hidden">ID Number 1</div>
<div id="2">ID Number 2</div>
<div id="hidden">ID Number 1</div>
<div id="2">ID Number 2</div>
<div id="hidden">ID Number 1</div>
<a href="#" id="hide">Hide Div</a>
```

Hope you can find this helpful.